# Convergence of $\sum_{n=0}^\infty (\frac{n}{n+1})^{n^2}e^n$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

Wolframalpha tells that $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty (\frac{n}{n+1})^{n^2}e^n$$ diverges since $$\lim_{n\to\infty}(\frac{n}{n+1})^{n^2}e^n=\sqrt{e}$$. How do you calculate this limit?

And also it tells that $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n(\frac{n}{n+1})^{n^2}e^n$$ is not convergent, but it didn't specify the reason. Can you give me one?

Comment: The second part is easy, since the sequence converges to a number $c\neq 0$, if you alternate it, you will get two accumulation points, and since only a the summation of a null-sequence can converge this one can't

Comment: $e^n $ goes to infinity and $\frac {n}{n+1}\approx1$ so i am afraid if WA is correct.

Comment: @archis you are only allowed to split a limit, if both converge, and they do not...

Comment: Yes exactly my point.

Comment: Why the self duplicate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, we can write

$$\begin{align}
\log\left(\left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right)^{n^2}e^n\right)&=n-n^2\log\left(1+\frac1n\right)\\\\
&=n-n^2\left(\frac1n-\frac{1}{2n^2}+O\left(\frac1{n^2}\right)\right)\\\\
&=\frac1{2}+O\left(\frac1n\right) 
\end{align}$$

Then, we have

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right)^{n^2}e^n=\lim_{n\to \infty}e^{\frac12+O\left(\frac1n\right)}=\sqrt e$$

as was to be shown!

Comment: Can it be calculated with more elementary math? I didn't learn about the approximation of $\log$ yet so...

Comment: or is it a Taylor series?

Comment: @user159234 It is Taylor series

Comment: It is [Taylor's Theorem with remainder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem#Taylor.27s_theorem_in_one_real_variable).

Answer (score 0):

Hint: if $u_n$ is your expression:
$$u_n=\exp(n-n^2\log(1+1/n))$$
and $ \log(1+x)=x-x^2/2+o(x^2)$ if $x\to 0$.
And the limit given is correct

Answer (score 0):

If $\sum_n a_n$ converges then $a_n \rightarrow 0$

The part $a_n \rightarrow 0$ is a necessary condition